# Google Map on a custom dialog not visible clear in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, dictionary, dialog

[image]

This is my dialog:

```
Dialog mPhramacyDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.style_dialog);
 mPhramacyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.f_pharmacy_details);
```

This is style.xml that I have passed:

fill_parent @color/app_text_color true true @color/app_text_color @dimen/med_report_list_text_size_large #fff

Comment: Some darkness is showing over it.
I have use  <style name="style_dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/app_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/med_report_list_text_size_large</item>
        <item name="android:background">#fff</item>
    </style>

Comment: Is this is the problem of style as i send you Dhawal Sodha Parma

Comment: i have solution for this problem :
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
by default dialog has backgroundDimEnabled  is true .